# Any way to specify cpu architecture with CircleCI?

Tags: circleci, circleci-2.0

If I'm using CircleCI to compile and deploy a portable binary, is there any way I can require the cpu architecture used to be amd64?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the only architecture available on CircleCI.

Comment: Do you know where that's documented?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's documented anywhere. I made a PR to add it to CircleCI Docs though: https://github.com/circleci/circleci-docs/pull/2228